# Two independent toc in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, titletoc

I'm summarizing two essays in a presentation in beamer and I need separate tables of content to give an overview over both of those essays. I tried `titletoc` but that doesn't seem to work.
I tried to use it like this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\startcontents
\printcontents{ }{1}{}

\begin{frame}
   \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{A regular section}
\section{Second regular section}

\stopcontents

\startcontents
\printcontents{ }{2}{}
 \begin{frame}
   \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section for other toc}
\section{Another section for other toc}

\stopcontents

\end{document}
```

What I get though is a really strange looking frame where it reads "section in toc" all over and after that a toc of all sections in my presentation is shown. This happens for both tables. Here is a picture of it.

[image: Look of both toc]

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest using the `\part` mechanism of `beamer` as shown in the following example. This creates two individual parts with separate tables of contents.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\part{First Project}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline of the first part}
\tableofcontents[part=1]
\end{frame}

\section{First section}
\section{another section}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\part{Second Project}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline of the second part}
\tableofcontents[part=2]
\end{frame}

\section{First section of second part}
\section{another section}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note: The optional argument (`[part=...]`) to `\tableofcontents` can as well be omitted, as this command will automatically display only the toc of the current part.

Comment: You don't really need `[part=xxx]` as `\tableofcontents` only displays the toc of the current part

Comment: @samcarter: Thanks for pointing this out. I was just sticking to the documentation, that explicitly includes this optional argument. Nevertheless if can safely be omitted. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: But the numbers do not restart from 1 in the second table of contents. Do you know how to do that?